# Using GeoPandas object.touches(geometry array) to have full list of Trues and Falses

Tags: geometry, geopandas, shapely, linestring

I try to pass a number of line strings inside the parentheses to have something like this in the output, I tried different formats but it did not work.

```py
a1.iloc[0].geometry.touches(a1['geometry'].values)
#desirable output
True
False
False
True
```

Is it possible to do something like this, or I must use `for`?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, [`touches()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.touches.html) works on a 1-to-1 row-wise manner. But you can also check if each geometry of GeoSeries touches a single geometry.

> `a1['geometry']` -> GeoSeries
>
> `a1.iloc[0].geometry` -> Single geometry

Therefore, use `a1['geometry'].touches(a1.iloc[0].geometry)`.